# Copying text from tool-tip in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to copy text from tool tip without using any addition plugins in javascript?

For Example :

```
<tr>
    <td title="NitiN">NitiN</td>
<tr>
```

when i hover on td tag it show me tooltip and that contains string "NitiN".
So,I want allow users to select texts on tooltip without using any addition JS plugins

Comment: which plugin you are using for tooltip?

Comment: copying some text using code is not something easy to do. You can show a popup with a textbox containing the text to allow user to copy it himself (the way YouTube allows users to copy the Video URL).

Comment: in order to do that you need to hand design a tooltip, browsers' built in tooltips wont work as you desire

Comment: @Manwal default browser tooltip

Comment: @King King thoses things i want to avoid

Comment: And what u want to do with that text after Copy on Hover?

Comment: For example i've some configuration info on tooltip then i will copy that info and just paste in my app or any where i want.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/4GHGF/)
**HTML**

```
<table><tbody>  
    <tr>  
        <td title="Mouse over me o_O">I'm just td</td>  
    </tr>  
</tbody></table>  
<div title="Thanks, man!">Hover me!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {  
    display: none;  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    top: 100%;  
    z-index: 2;  
    background-color: grey;  
    border: 1px solid black;  
    border-radius: 10px;  
    padding: 10px;  
    min-width: 200px;  
}
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function( windowLoadE ) {  
    var elements = document.body.querySelectorAll( "[title]" );  
    for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {  
        elements[ i ].style.position = "relative";  
        var tooltip = document.createElement( "div" );  
        tooltip.setAttribute( "class", "tooltip" );  
        tooltip.innerText = elements[ i ].getAttribute( "title" );  
        elements[ i ].appendChild( tooltip );  
        elements[ i ].addEventListener( "mouseenter", function( elMouseEneterE ) {  
            var tooltip = this.querySelector( "div.tooltip" );  
            tooltip.style.display = "inline";  
        } );  
        elements[ i ].addEventListener( "mouseleave", function( elMouseEneterE ) {  
            var tooltip = this.querySelector( "div.tooltip" );  
            tooltip.style.display = "none";  
        } );  
    }  
} );
```

But better use any plugin, like [this](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Comment: @KingRider you can use jquery ui tooltip plugin https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ - last link in my post.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 var copy =$('#td_id').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link, Use `plugins`  as its not default behaviour of tooltip to stay opened on hover for copying .

[here](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip) and

[here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/07/jquery-tooltip-plugin.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use .text() in mouse enter using  jquery;

```
 var copy =$(this).text();
```

in JavaScript

```
var copy =this.innerHTML;
```

Comment: I want allow user to select text on tooltip :(

Comment: @Bala : i didn't downvoted. but this is not what op want. he want to allow user to copy text of tooltip.

Comment: @AmitKumar what is copy .

Comment: @Bala , if Title pops up , on hover , it should stay same ,and user will be able to do Copy and then paste somewhere else

Comment: @Bala : i think you haven't read question yet. read it again.